# What is the best book on halacha?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah, kitzur-shulchan-aruch

What is the best book for learning halacha systematically? I'm considering 3 options:

(a) Peninei Halacha

(b) Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

(c) Mishnah Brurah

I'm trying to understand the benefits and downsides of these books.

Comment: first, isn't this purely opinion? Unless you can determine what system you want and what kind of content you are looking for, asking "best" will get any number of opinions. Second, why do you exclude so many other options? Third, which halachot are you trying to learn?

Comment: Aruch Hashulchan is much better than all three (if you have to pick one which is already a severe limitation on any study program)

Comment: Ask your rabbi.

Comment: Try tzurbah Mrabanan,it was done very well on all 4 parts of Shulchan Aruch ,not every siman ,but it goes based off topic ,if you learn all volumes you will be very well versed in halacha. However ,nothing can be better than learning the tur bais yosef all the way down ,but that requires a lot of time and dedication

Comment: Note MB is limited to OC only. KSA needs an edition with more recent piskei halacha as it brings one opinion only, not always mainstream. Peninei Halacha is much simpler to learn but is not meant to have the same depth. You need to be much clearer about your criteria (breadth, depth, objective, time commitment) to get useful answers for you.